# Homemade factorial function in Python

Tags: python, factorial

I know a code that works, but I can't seem to figure out why this code only returns `0`. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
def factorial(x):
    hold = 1
    count = x
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        while count > 0:
            count -= 1
            hold *= count
            return hold
```

Comment: you need to set `hold` to 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"

Comment: The function always returns "0"

Comment: I edited the post to make it more clear, also adding in @DanielA.White's suggestion. I still get the same problem.

Comment: You decrement before multiplying. Switch the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns `0` because `count` will be finally `0` in your last loop. Loop will execute for `count = 1` and you will multiply hold by `0` since you subtract `1` from count ***before*** multiplying. You have to subtract `1` after multiplication:

```
def factorial(x):
    hold = 1
    count = x
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        while count > 0:
            hold *= count
            count -= 1  # moved this statement to the bottom
        return hold
```

However much better function would be:

```
def factorial(x):
   hold = 1
   for number in xrange(2, x+1): # or range in python 3
       hold *= number
   return hold
```